# how are commit DAGS stored in GIT

Tags: git, directed-acyclic-graphs

How are DAGs stored internally in Git?
As an example, consider the DAG
A->B->C->D
->E->F->G.

You somehow to save the following information. A->B, B->C,C->D,A->E,E->F,F->G.
So how is it stored? Given a particular node how can you tell what branch it is on?

Comment: In your example, is `A` the parent of `B` or the other way around?

Answer (score 4):

Just so that we don't get lost in terminology: A DAG in general is a graph *G = (V, E)*, composed of a vertex set *V* and edge set *E*, where each edge in the edge-set imposes a direction (also called an *arc*), and there are no cycles (no path from any vertex back to itself through the various arcs).  A typical representation of edges is as pairs of vertices, e.g., if the nodes are represented as single uppercase letters (as in your example) we might have *<A, B>* in the edge-set *E* to indicate that vertex *A* connects to vertex *B*, in that direction.  That is, *<A, B>* means there is an arc from *A* to *B*.

Git does not use this typical representation.  Instead, each "vertex" is a commit, whose unique identifier is its hash ID (and I, at least, tend to call these "nodes" in the graph instead of "vertices").  Each commit lists its *parent* commit(s), by their hash IDs.  Hence, if commit `A` (really `a234567890123456789012345678901234567890` or some such) is the parent of commit `B` (really `b876543210...`), there's nothing in `A` naming `B`, but there is a parent ID in `B` naming `A`.

In other words, the edges in a Git graph are all *backwards*.

Meanwhile, branch names point to a single commit node, which is designated the *tip commit* of that branch.  For instance `master` may resolve to `08bb3500a2a718c3c78b0547c68601cafa7a8fd9`.

The name `HEAD` either contains the current branch *name*, or contains the raw hash ID of the current commit.  Using `git rev-parse`, we can turn any name (including `HEAD`) into the appropriate ID:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
08bb3500a2a718c3c78b0547c68601cafa7a8fd9
```

We can now answer these questions:

> So how is it stored?

A commit node exists in the repository as an object of type `commit` whose contents are (after the usual compression is expanded) just plain text in the format shown by `git cat-file -p`:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | sed 's/@/ /'
tree a775288b86ae652ea163357939d852cdd927eed6
parent 36cafe44443fcca9eb35399ef0e9bfe289ec5dde
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1468959976 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1468959976 -0700

Sixth batch of topics for 2.10

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

This tells us that there is an arc from `08bb3500a2a718c3c78b0547c68601cafa7a8fd9` to `36cafe44443fcca9eb35399ef0e9bfe289ec5dde`.

To find the complete graph—the set of all edges and vertices/nodes—we begin with ***all suitable starting points*** (see below) and read these objects from the repository.  For commit objects, we read their `parent` lines, which provide additional node IDs and also provide an arc: from the node we just read, to the node named in each `parent` line.  (A merge commit has multiple `parent` lines, rather than one `parent` line listing multiple IDs, but of course that's pretty trivial.  Note also that each *annotated tag* object points to one other object, usually a commit, so when we find an object of type `tag` we should read its `object` line, and repeat this process until we find a non-tag object.  But we won't find any such objects if we start only from branch names; see below.)

(In a normal non-Git DAG, no arc is especially distinguished, but in Git, the *first* parent listed for each node *is* distinguished from any additional parents, and the order matters when using the suffix-`^` syntax.  In particular, when you make a merge commit, the ID that used to be `HEAD` will become the first parent of the new merge commit.)

> Given a particular node how can you tell what branch it is on?

This question has a flaw: it assumes that a node is on a branch.

A node may, in fact, be on *no* branch, or on *many* branches.

Let's return now to the notion of ***all suitable starting points***.  What starting-points are there?  If we had a typical graph representation, we would have the full set of vertices (or nodes) listed somewhere.  In Git, we don't have this.<sup>1</sup>  Instead, we have *references*, which are mostly names starting with `refs/`.  Branches and tags are forms of references, starting with `refs/heads/` and `refs/tags/` respectively.  The Git command `git for-each-ref` lets you find all of these references.

There are a few special purposes references that do not start with `refs`: `HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, and so on.  Some Git commands need to look here as well.  For your particular case, however, we care only about branch names, and all of those do start with `refs/`—in fact, with `refs/heads/`—so we can run `git for-each-ref refs/heads` to list them all.  (The `for-each-ref` command adds the extra `/` for us here, on the theory that it's like a directory-list operation.)

Hence, to find out if node *X* (for some *X*) is on one or more branches, and if so, which ones, we start from the node ID stored under each branch name.  That identifies the *tip commit* of that branch.  We then follow that commit's parents, and those nodes' parents, and so on until we run out of parents (using whatever search algorithm we like).  If we encounter node *X* along the way, node *X* is on that branch.

Thus, node *X* is contained in each branch from which we can find *X* starting from that branch's tip commit.  This is what `git branch --contains` shows.

(Tag names generally point either directly to commit nodes (a "lightweight tag") or to a tag object (an "annotated tag").  So if we allow all references, we must be prepared to handle tags.  Branch names are constrained to point only to commit nodes.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, we can do an exhaustive traversal of the entire repository to look for all objects.  This is what `git fsck` does, for instance, or `git gc`.

Answer (score 2):

Each commit has N parents, with N an integer that is equal to or bigger than 0. A root commit has 0 parents. A non-merge commit has 1 parent. A merge commit has 2 or more parents. A parent is another commit. Each commit except the root stores the sha1(s) of its parent(s). Thus the commits are organized as a DAG. Knowing a commit, we can tell all of its ancestors. `git log -1 <commit> --pretty=%P` can output the commit's parent(s).

In one git repo, there may be one or more DAGs. A branch is a ref that points to, or an anchor that attaches to a commit (or another branch) . It's a bit like the pointer in C, with the commit as a struct or class variable and sha1 as its address. The branch can be moved from one commit to another. Sometimes it moves automatically, via introducing a new commit including `git commit`, `git rebase`, `git merge`, `git cherry-pick`, etc. Sometimes it moves by our will via `git reset`.

When we say a commit is on a branch, it can be understood in another way, that this commit is equal to, or the ancestor of that commit that is referred to by the branch. `git branch --contains <commit> --all` can tell which branches the commit is on.

Comment: Probably everyone will get what you mean when you say "there many be one or more DAGs", but mathematically it might be better to say that the DAG need not even be weakly connected.  A graph with disconnected subgraphs is still just one big graph, after all. :-)  Also, a new, empty Git repo has the null graph, and if you count DAGs by their connectedness, you would have to say that in this situation you have no DAGs at all.  (But these are all just nits.)

Comment: @torek Thank you very much =)